# Where does outlook save junk mail rules?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I set all mails as junk unless I approve it. The problem is I created an imap account and then delete my pop account.

Then all of my junk mail rules are gone.

Is junk mail rules saved with the account or what?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Outlook stores Junk Email configuration in the store you're configuring it for.